# Как убрать буквицу в FB2(xml) документе?

Tags: html, вёрстка, xml

оцифровал и вычитал книжку по программированию, в ней есть предметный указатель в эл.версии я его оставил и сделал гиперссылки.
Часть предметного указателя именуется с маленькой часть с большой буквы, так вот, там где с большой ставится буквица.

**как от неё можно избавиться?** (ненашол тег/атрибут fb-xml)

*не предлагать*

1. написать первый символ с маленькой (aNSI, bASIC и т.п.)
2. отключить буквицу в читалке (в других местах она нужна)
3. вставить символ пробела до первой буквы и\или вставить html пробел-табуляцию (как минимум в алридере(wm) непашет)
4. не предлагать CSS

Comment: Дайте линк на книжку, которая у Вас получилась.

Comment: @ReinRaus 
проблема уже решена :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема с интерпритатором решена так

```
<p><a><a>TEXT</p>  //просто тега a
<p><a> <a>TEXT</p> //тег a с пробелом
```

в итоге управление передается тегу **а**(который нихрена неделает) и тег **р** забывает о буквице...

Comment: Обычно такие способы решения называются костылем :)  
Все же дайте ссылку на книгу- мне для себя. Тоже занимаюсь конвертированием книг в fb2, но никогда не сталкивался с буквицей.

Comment: @ReinRaus 
http://nnm-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=582262

из интересного это юникод для форматирования кода программ и буквица.